# How can I merge two or more table into a single table with all columns name of all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, join

How can I merge two or more table into a single table with all columns name of all tables
[This is table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRgUJ.png)

[This is table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR0Kw.png)

[Can I get new table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/legbR.png)

Comment: What's the connection between the two tables?  Putting them together would require some connection, some relationship between them.   In your third picture, it's not clear there is one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt was made.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join tables in this way, you have to have additional column to join on, one of possibilities is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select T1.[date] [Table1_date],
       T1.[als] [Table1_als],
       T1.[zxc] [Table1_zxc],
       T2.[date] [Table2_date],
       T2.[bls] [Table2_bls],
       T2.[zxc] [Table2_zxc]
from (
    select row_number() over (order by [date]) [rn],[date],[als],[zxc] from Table1
) [T1] left /*right - depends which table has more rows*/ join (
    select row_number() over (order by [date]) [rn],[date],[bls],[zxc] from Table2
) [T2] on T1.[rn] = T2.[rn]
```

In order to join multiple tables (>2), first table to occure in query should be one with maximum amount of records. Then you can use series of `left join` with the rest of tables, joining on column generated by `row_number()`.